# How to validate strike out names, Property and Motorcar in TypeScript code using visual studio code editor?

Tags: typescript, playwright

[image]> [In the below HTML, need to validate strike out text Property and Motorcar using TypeScript using visual studio code editor ]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some css in play here using `text-decoration: line-through`, you should be able to assert it like so:

`await expect(page.getByTestId('Property')).toHaveCSS('text-decoration', 'line-through');`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing! :)